# pagination ngx bootstrap for angular2

Tags: angular

i have a probleme with pagination first i have 21 objects in database so when i get them i want show them with pagination just now , all things works good but i think that pagination module has a number of row to display by default is like it took 10 a row per page and not 4 per page

```
export class GroupComponent implements OnInit {


public maxSize:number = 5;
  bigTotalItems:number = 175;
  bigCurrentPage:number = 1;
  numPages:number = 0;
  itemsPerPage = 4;
  groups : any; 
  myVar:Boolean=false;

 constructor(private groupeService:DataServiceService) { 
    parent.displayGroupeIcon();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getListGroups();
  }

getListGroups(){

  this.groupeService.getGroupsByPageAndSize(this.bigCurrentPage-1,this.itemsPerPage).subscribe(groups => {
  this.groups=groups;
  this.numPages=groups.totalPages;
  this.bigTotalItems=groups.totalElements;
  this.myVar = true;
             });

}
```

and this the template

```
   <table class="table table-striped">
           <thead>
            <tr>
             <th >Identifiant </th>
              <th >Nom </th>
                <th >Image</th>

                <th ></th>
                <th ></th>
            </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody *ngIf="myVar">

           <tr *ngFor="let groupe of groups.content" >
           <td >{{groupe.idGroupe}} </td>
           <td >{{groupe.nom}} </td>
           <td >{{groupe.imageUrl}}</td>
     <td ><button  class="btn btn-warning" >Update <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
            <td ><button  class="btn ink-reaction btn-danger">Delete <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
            </tr>



        </tbody>
        </table>



<div class="col-md-6">
  <pagination [totalItems]="bigTotalItems" [(ngModel)]="bigCurrentPage" [maxSize]="maxSize" class="pagination-sm"
              [boundaryLinks]="true" [rotate]="false"  (click)="getListGroups()"></pagination>
</div>
bigTotalItems : {{bigTotalItems| json}}

numPages : {{numPages|json}}
```

Heeelp pleaseee and thanks in advice.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

i resolv it i just adding  [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage" directive in my selector of pagination